# Garage door shudders on initial opening, then works fine

Tags: garage, garage-door

My garage door shudders on initial opening and then runs smooth.  The shudder is a moderately violent shake that is short, maybe first 6" of travel.  Motor has plenty of power and seems to be working fine.  It has no issues going down.  This only happens after the door has been idle for a few hours.  Subsequent openings even an hour or two later run smooth on initial opening with no shudder.

My guess is something having to do with spring tension.

First thing is to figure out what I need to be looking at.  I am open to trying basic garage door maintenance but don't want to touch the spring and other high energy elements.

Unit is a Liftmaster, maybe 10 years old.  Came with the house when I moved here 4 years ago.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Shuddering usually is the result of loose or misaligned moving parts on the door or opener. Tighten down the nuts and bolts on the rails, the wheels and travelers along both sides of the door. Check your installation manual on proper alignment procedure or look online. Also check the stability of the mounting framework for thr opener and chain support. It should all be firmly bolted down. Hinges as well.

Comment: I would disconnect it from the opener and lift it by hand to see if you can feel anything binding.

Comment: Garage doors don't need openers.  They should operate easily by hand.  If they start having problems, you will notice it instantly when working by hand. However the motor will just force it, making things worse and worse until the door kills you. Yeah, they can kill you.

Comment: HoneyDo is correct, but also check to see if the track is dented/bent/twisted/damaged. Especially in the first few inches by the floor if the problem seems to go away once the door lifts past a certain height.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I had a garage door opener that was powerful enough to compensate for a broken spring (out of two). The door was ridiculously heavy to open by hand, and required about 4 people to hold it up.